# iPad Not Respecting AutoLayout Constraints from Interface Builder

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, interface-builder

I am using AutoLayout in my iOS App. On the iPhone, the `UITableView` extends to both edges of the screen; however, on the iPad, it stops a few pixels short of the edges.

Here are my AutoLayout constraints:

[image: constraints]

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image: background issue]

Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing and Leading space is -16.00000, make it 0 by uncheck `constraint to margin` option...Because it is -16.000, it makes -16 space from edges...
You should done it like below image...

[image]

It pinned your edges to `0` as you want it